# Ambiquity in choosing the main class in NEtbeans though a public class is declared

Tags: java, program-entry-point

While running this code in netbeans,it asks me to select the main class.. why doesn't it by default choose the public class to be the main class and run?

```
class Staticclasss2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello world from staticclasss2");
    }
}
public class Staticclasss{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello world from Staticclasss");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> why doesn't it by default choose the public class to be the main class and run?

Simply because the access level of a class is not an aspect which is relevant when picking an entry point class. While `main` has to be public, the class itself doesn't... and often you wouldn't want it to be. (After all, you're typically *not* calling this from other code. I'd rather be in a situation where `main` could be private, but that's another matter.)

Both options are equally valid, so the situation is inherently ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The class containing `main()` method **does not have** to be public, just the `main()` method **MUST** be public for the JRE to pick it up to start your program.

So in your case there are two classes that contain a public `main()` method, so netbeans asks you to choose from the two options.

Same is the scenario with **Eclipse**.